# Change in behavior

Tags: dogs

We have an older pit/husky mix rescue dog he is about 7.5 years old and recently has gone from an indoor dog wanting to be with us to an outside dog who is afraid to come inside. He has been starting to not eat unless it’s also outside. The only thing we can think of is we recently used a bug zapper inside (not on him) and he is afraid of it. Or he may of been abused in the past. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: When does he show his fear? Is he visibly afraid of the zapper when shown? Are there any other things besides going inside he is visibly afraid of?

Comment: It is a hand held zapper and we removed it from the house.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off the bug zapper and see if that solves the issue.

Many bug zappers emit high frequency sound waves that are advertised as "cannot be heard by most humans and house pets" where **MOST** is a keyword.

It may be that the sound the zapper makes is so annoying to him that he would rather be outside.